# What is the shortest way to enclose $n$ circles?

Tags: geometry, circles

What is the shortest way to enclose $n$ circles of radius $1$? Is there a formula for the length of the shortest path? I have tried to find the shortest way, up to $n\leq10$. Below are the shortest ways of those I have found, but there may be shorter ways than these.

| n | length |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | $2\pi$ |
| 2 | $2\pi+4$ |
| 3 | $2\pi+6$ |
| 4 | $2\pi+8$ |
| 5 | $2\pi+10$ |
| 6 | $2\pi+8+2\sqrt{3}$ |
| 7 | $2\pi+12$ |
| 8 | $2\pi+14$ |
| 9 | $2\pi+12+2\sqrt{3}$ |
| 10 | $2\pi+16$ |

[image: Path and circles]

Comment: At the very least, it seems like you always get $2\pi$ from the curvy bits (no sharp corners and all convex means one full circle worth of arc), plus some straight bits that all are grid distances in a hexagonal grid. At least that will be the case if the circles are always tightly packed. Which isn't obviously the solution.

Comment: You want to minimize the length of certain "convex hulls". See this connected document: https://users.astro.ufl.edu/~kallrath/files/KallrathFrey-2019.pdf . See as well here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64516/packing-circles